# When Spring sees <task:annotation-driven/> in a webapp what contexts are checked?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have  in a servlet's application context XML file (`/app/feature`). There is also an application context for the web application as a whole (i.e. for the servlet context `/app`) and there are multiple servlets with other XML files. I understand the spring context for `/app` acts as a partent for the ones at `/app/feature`.

When I put `<task:annotation-driven/>` in the child application context which beans are checked for @Async and @Scheduled annotations ?

Comment: That child's and the app context's.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it depends on the component-scan base..

Answer (score 1):

The `task:annotation-driven` register BeanPostProcessors like `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` that are scoped per-container:

```
...beans that are defined in one container are not post-processed by 
a BeanPostProcessor defined in another container, even if both containers 
are part of the same hierarchy.
```

Comment: Can you define "container"..? JVM?

Comment: An ApplicationContext instance (the IoC Container), see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The inner logic is like this, for example: `applicationContext.xml` is you said parent file and `spring-servlet.xml` is you said child file. then when the tomcat starts up, first all the beans in applicationContext.xml will be instantiated, second all the beans in spring-servlet.xml will be instantiated, then something will happen, if bean A is configed in both applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml, then the first instance of A will be override by the second one. So if you add the `<task:annotation-driven/>` in `applicationContext.xml`, it doesn't work, because the whole bean has been overridden by the bean instantiated in spring-servlet.xml.

Answer (score 0):

It will look for @Async, where as @Scheduled will gives you ability to schedule the execution like after every 5000 ms.